# How partner users with same account are getting access to each other's records

Tags: sharing, user, owd, partner, with-sharing

I want to check how two partner users with the same account are getting access to each other's partner record.
Owd of user object - private
No sharing rules on user object.

Also, when i query usershare record, i can only see the owner has access to that user record.

And in the class defined as "with sharing" - i am getting the result from user query if i try to read another partner user record.

Then how is this user sharing working? Can anyone help me here please.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the article [Control Which Users Experience Cloud Site Users Can See](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_user_sharing.htm&type=5)

> When setting up sharing for external users, you have three settings to consider. These settings take effect only when the org-wide default external access for the User object **is set to Private**. If the org-wide external default for the User object is set to Public Read Only, all users can see one another, regardless of site-specific user visibility settings enabled.
>
> Portal User Visibility: If enabled, portal users in the same customer or partner portal account can see each other, regardless of the organization-wide defaults. Partner users with a Partner Community license or equivalent can also see the Salesforce user who owns their partner portal account.
>
> Site User Visibility: This setting controls whether user sharing is available for authenticated users in your org’s sites. If enabled, you have the option of selecting See other members of this site, which turns visibility on or off, on a site-by-site basis.
>
> Guest User Visibility: The Let guest users see other members of this site setting controls whether user sharing is available for unauthenticated (guest) users in your Experience Cloud sites. You grant guest user visibility on a site-by-site basis by selecting Let guest users see other members of this site, which turns visibility on or off.

You must have `Portal User Visibility` enabled. You'll need to enable  `Site User Visibility` and set to `OFF`